# Keep responsive image overlay the same size as image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an absolute positioned image. The image has an overlay that should always be the same size as that of the image.

Note that the image is responsive. Meaning, if the user resizes the window the image will increase in length and or height. The overlay must react accordingly.

The issue I face is that if, say, the user increases the width of the browser, the overlay increases in height in accordance to the image, however, the image also increases in height in order to not create a disturbed picture. The increase in the image despite the user only increased the width of the browser creates a size difference between the overlay and the image.

Gif of the issue: https://gyazo.com/e90fd418df20a622712b73422d1022b8

How should I go about solving this issue?

This is a very bad approach of mine:
*Basically I had a **div#img-wrapper** that contains both the img and the overlay. The **overlay** and **image** was then supposed to stay the same size as the **div#img-wrapper**.*

```css
#img-wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    left: 35%;
    top: 55%;
    background: yellow;
    width: 50%;
}

img {
   border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 55;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 50%; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black;">
  <div id="img-wrapper">
   <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12225358/Pug-On-White-01.jpg" alt="">
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You have to show your code

Comment: Well my code is wrong, it is not hard to realize my code won't work, I need to approach the issue differently. You still think I should show it?

Comment: Yes, please post the code. Or, even a simple codepen/jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue you're facing. It helps understand the requirement(s) and what you've done so far.

Comment: Maybe your approach is not wrong and can be fixed easily, it's hard to tell if you don't show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#img-wrapper {
  background: yellow;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-wrapper"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12225358/Pug-On-White-01.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, but your solution doesn't work, please take a look at my updated fiddle. I forgot to tell that I wanted it inside a div that fills up 50% of the width of the body.

Comment: I updated my code.  Putting 50% on the image wrapper seemed to achieve this.

Comment: Well, take a look at my fiddle, it clearly doesn't work when you wrap the "img-wrapper" inside a div that takes up 50% of the width and 100% of the height.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I just changed your CSS a little.
So, you would set the height of your wrapper to auto. Then take off the absolute positioning of the image to be set as relative to the wrapper. Then position the absolute overlay top and left 0 and give height of 100% to fill the parent wrapper element.

```
#img-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background: yellow;
    height: auto;
}
img {
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.1;
    z-index: 5;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I mean, your solution works but for some reason there is always a little bit of the overlay that is "sticking out". Take a look: https://gyazo.com/90d2868a5ce64bfd5263a38832836c57

Comment: I made an html file and ran the code in four different browsers. I don't see that issue. https://www.screencast.com/t/TTVLPzVuFB0Y

Answer (score 0):

you can try with pseudo-class. here the example

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.img-wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}

.img-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="">
</div>
```